# How do I stop a disabled tkinter button from being greyed out?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Basically, I've got a tkinter button with an image on it, and when I disable the button it greys out a square around the image and looks pretty bad. Is there any way to stop this from happening while keeping the button disabled?

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the button, you can unbind the callback:

```
button['command']=0
```

Comment: Also, if you want to make it stay in place, you can do button['relief']='sunken'

Comment: Actually I've tried something similar to that, but the reason I didn't do it is actually the opposite of what you were saying. I actually don't want the button to sink when it's clicked. Like it goes back to raised when i let off the click but it becomes sunken as long as I have the button held down and I'd like to avoid that.